# Apache beam KafkaIO offset management to external data stores

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to read from multiple kafka brokers using KafkaIO on apache beam. The default option for offset management is to the kafka partition itself (no longer using zookeper from kafka >0.9). With this setup, when i restart the job/pipeline, there is issue with duplicate and missing records.

From what i read, the best way to handle this is to manage offset to external data stores. Is it possible to do this with current version of apache beam and KafkaIO? I am using 2.2.0 version right now.

And, after reading from kafka,i will write it to BigQuery. Is there a setup in KafkaIO where I can set the committed message only after i insert the message to BigQuery? I can only find auto commit setup right now.

Answer (score 0):

In Dataflow, you can [update a job](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline) rather than restarting from scratch. The new job resumes from the last checkpointed state, ensuring exactly-once processing. This works for KafkaIO source as well. The auto-commit option in Kafka consumer configuration helps but it is not atomic with Dataflow internal state, which implies restarted job might have small fraction of duplicate or missing messages.